# Submit batch job written in python on azure

Tags: python, azure, curl, batch-processing, azure-hdinsight

How to submit batch job written in python on azure. I am looking for similar to this but not for java but for python.

```
curl -k --user "admin:mypassword1!" -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{ "file":"wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/SparkSimpleTest.jar", "className":"com.microsoft.spark.test.SimpleFile" }' "https://mysparkcluster.azurehdinsight.net/livy/batches"
```

Answer (score 0):

The MapReduce jobs for Java and Python are different.

The Java MapReduce program packaged a jar file as a job directly runs on Hadoop.

But the python MapReduce job was separated into two files `mapper.py` and `reducer.py` running on the Hadoop Streaming via `STDIN` and `STDOUT`.

Please refer to the document http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/, and upload the mapper & reducer python script into the HDInsight, then write a shell script as a job for running on Hadoop.